# Converting a mysql_real_escape_string function to mysqli

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have the following code, within a larger php script:

```
$FullSQL = $inSQL;
        foreach($ROW as $item) {
            $ItemName = (string)$item->getName();
            $fieldValue = $ROW->$ItemName;
            $FullSQL = $FullSQL . "'" . mysql_real_escape_string($fieldValue) . "', ";
        }
        $inSQL_len = strlen($FullSQL) -2;
        $FullSQL=substr($FullSQL, 0, $inSQL_len ) . ")";
        echo "INSERTED FullSQL=" . $FullSQL . "<br><br>";

        if (!mysqli_query($con,$FullSQL)) { die('Error insering tmporder: ' . $FullSQL . " ERROR:" . mysqli_error()); }
        else {
             echo "INSERTED inSQL=" . $FullSQL . "<br><br>";
        }

    }
}
```

I've managed to convert the whole script to mysqli, except that above section. As expected, the `mysql_real_escape_string($fieldValue)` part is generating a mysql depreciation error.

How to I convert that piece of code to use mysqli? It requires two variables, and there is only one.

Thanks.

Comment: `mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $string)`

Comment: Prepared statements would be the more recommended way to go: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
 mysqli_real_escape_string ($con, $fieldValue);
```

Where `$con` is your link identifier returned by [mysqli_connect()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php) or [mysqli_init()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.init.php).

---

If we compare syntax of [mysqli_real_escape_string()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) and [mysql_real_escape_string()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) we have

```
 mysqli_real_escape_string ($link, $string);
 mysql_real_escape_string ($string[, $link=NULL]);
```

So old function also had same arguments but in different order and `$link` was optional in deprecated version.

---

If you decide to use object style instead of procedural use it like this

```
 $con = new mysqli ("host", "user", "pwd", "db");
 ...
 $safe_string = $con->real_escape_string ($string);
```